# Infinite product in terms of a special function or integral

Tags: special-functions, infinite-product

Define

$p_\delta^{\pm,q}\left(z\right)=\prod\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(1\pm e^{-2z\sqrt{\frac{\delta^2}4+\pi^2\left(n-\frac q2\right)^2}}\right)$

and

$P_\delta^{\pm,q}\left(z\right)=\prod\limits_{n\in\mathbb Z,\,n\equiv q\,\left(\text{mod }2\right)}\left(1\pm e^{-z\sqrt{\delta^2+\pi^2n^2}}\right)$

where $z\in\mathbb C$ with $\mathrm{Re}\left(z\right)>0$ and $\delta\in\mathbb R$ and $q=0,1$. Can any of these functions be expressed in terms of some known special functions or in terms of an integral? If possible, both representations would be great. Also, what properties do these functions have? Are they analytic in $z$ and are the smooth at $\delta=0$? Any progress made on any of the functions would be really helpful. Please do comment/answer even if there's a partial answer to any of these questions.

Comment: This may be a fruitless remark, but it may yield something to consider the natural log of the product as the sum of the natural logs of the addends, and then Taylor expanding the natural log around 1.

Comment: Whence the products?

Comment: @CadeReinberger, I tried that but I couldn't get much out of it. It only helps when $\mathrm{Re}\left(z\right)$ is large, but what will that tell me about analyticity in $z$ / smoothness in $\delta$?

Comment: Well, honestly if I'd have been able to use it to get anything, I'd have done it and told you. It was an just idea that might somehow be useful, so I thought I'd comment it.

Comment: Try to express these in terms of more traditional modular forms or theta functions. (to that end, it might be prudent to use some other name for the $q$ parameter above).

Comment: Can you help me out? How would I do express them in terms of modular forms or theta functions?